# Scala class List, how find source code?

Tags: scala

I want copy several methods of List. But I cant find source code of this class?
I check  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9 and C:\Program Files\Java\jre-9\ for scala class. Search did not find anything.

Comment: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.3/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L1 is that what you are looking for???

Comment: @Pavel yes! thank you!

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why would you expect to find the source code for one programming language in the source code for a totally different, completely unrelated programming language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel free to accept this as answer:

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.3/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L1